# Add an item to an outline group

Tags: list, swiftui, outline

How can I add a new item to a list structured with OutlineGroup?
In detail, how can I write the code to:

1. list all the possible categories
2. in an AddView, select the category.

Comment: Can you show what you have so far and then list where you're having a problem? SO works best with specific problems.

Comment: You need to be more specific, maybe you could share code ask about your problem accordingly